# Could a closed looped of wire with current move itself?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

The question starts from this:

Place two tiny current segments on $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, each heading to positive $x$ direction and positive $y$ direction. By magnetic force $dF=idl\times B$, the segments will be driven to positive $y$ direction and positive $x$ direction respectively, resulting in a non-zero net internal force in the system of two segments. This is because momentum can be carried by the fields.

But the case above is impossible because there is no current segment; it has to form a closed loop. So, in the case it is a closed loop of current, is it possible that it creates a non-zero net internal force?

By internal force, I mean the magnetic force exerted to the current loop that is only generated by the magnetic field that the current loop generated itself.

I know I could integrate the net force using the Biot-Savart law, but that integration was too tough for me, and I would like to know if there is a fundamental explanation to this problem rather than mere computation. (If it is impossible, as my intuition tells)

If it is actually possible, that would be really surprising!

Answer (score 0):

There are two fundamental reasons why this doesn't work like that:

1. Lenz's law:

> the direction of the electric current induced in a conductor by a changing magnetic field is such that the magnetic field created by the induced current opposes changes in the initial magnetic field.

This is basically a manifestation of energy conservation, preventing run-away EM fields from appearing.

2. Conservation of momentum:

To generate any force on the loop as a whole, we need to generate a force on something else. This is possible, as e.g. photons carry (a tiny amount of) momentum, but this setup won't radiate a large number of photons (in fact by Lenz's law it will just be a coil without current).

Basically, always check against fundamental conservation laws when thinking about stuff like this. If something generates energy out of nowhere, it's unphysical.